# How to create a button in GTK without padding

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I need to create a button without massive padding. Changing the css of a button to `padding: 0px` doesn't do anything.

[Here's what buttons look like by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBqAt.png)

[Here's what I want the button to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIa0o.png)

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why it wasn't working before, but doing `button { padding: 0px; }` *does* work…